# Strange issue where I cannot download source code of SourceForge project with CVS

Tags: cvs, sourceforge

I am trying to download source code for a project from Sourceforge.net
I have followed the instructions on my Windows using CVS but get a strange problem:

```
Documents\cpluplus> cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@gretl.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gretl login
Logging in to :pserver:anonymous@gretl.cvs.sourceforge.net:2401/cvsroot/gretl
CVS password:
```

When I enter a blank password as suggested, I get:

```
cvs [login aborted]: reading from server: Connection reset by peer
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is another option in SoureForge CVS repository web viewer. You can download a GNU tarball.

Comment: I should mention the error mentioned is where the SF are overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You really should ask this question either in the SourceForge IRC channel (#sourceforge on Freenode) or open a support ticket at https://sourceforge.net/support

As it happens, anonymous CVS is currently down for maintenance. Should be back up some time this evening.